# A way to access global hash table "avoid" lock

Tags: multithreading, math, lock-free

In my project, there are N threads to access a global hash table, and this cann't be avoid. So I think I should use a lockfree hash table or something else. After all, I choose to try something else, rather lockfree hash table, because lockfree hash is usually for special purpose and is not so easy to use.

My idea is:

There are **N** threads to access a global hash table, so I spilt the hash table to **M** sub-hashtables, where **M** >= **N**. At any time, the sum of all threads to choose N sub-hashtables from M sub-hashtables is pow(M, N), and the sum of choose N sub-hashtables from M sub-hashtables which are unique is P(M, N), so the rate of there is no race conditions is P(M, N)/pow(M, N), and the rate of there is race conditions is **1-P(M,N)/pow(M,N)**, that is 1-M!/(M-N)!/pow(M,N).

My calculate, *r* means the rate of there is race condition:

threads num=2

```
n=2, m=2 r=0.5
n=2, m=3 r=0.333333
n=2, m=4 r=0.25
n=2, m=5 r=0.2
n=2, m=6 r=0.166667
n=2, m=7 r=0.142857
n=2, m=8 r=0.125
n=2, m=9 r=0.111111
n=2, m=10 r=0.1
n=2, m=11 r=0.0909091
...
n=2, m=100 r=0.01
...
```

thread num=3

```
n=3, m=3 r=0.777778
n=3, m=4 r=0.625
n=3, m=5 r=0.52
n=3, m=6 r=0.444444
n=3, m=7 r=0.387755
...
n=3, m=29 r=0.10107
...
```

thread num=5

```
n=5, m=5 r=0.9616
n=5, m=6 r=0.907407
n=5, m=7 r=0.850062
n=5, m=8 r=0.794922
n=5, m=9 r=0.743941
...
n=5, m=96 r=0.100425
```

thread num=8

```
n=8, m=8 r=0.997597
n=8, m=9 r=0.99157
n=8, m=10 r=0.981856
n=8, m=11 r=0.968964
n=8, m=12 r=0.953583
...
n=8, m=268 r=0.100095
```

The advantage is choose a suitable m, we can get lockfree at 90% time

The disadvantage is we waste lots of resources.

Is my idea right? Are there some better solutions?

Comment: Did you explain why you think locking would be bad? Hash operations are quite fast, so a simple mutex seems appropriate... unless you have another reason.

Referencing the rest of your question, what is `P(M,N)`? And how are you sure you can split your hash table when `M >> N` (i.e. `M` is very large... how big is your hash table?)

Comment: @roliu Q1:Because in my situation, there are total 800K read/write access to the global hash table per second through 8 threads, I try to spilt it to thread local to get cache friendly and avoid lock, but I cann't. So I have to choose lockfree hashtable. If one thread get the lock, others have to go to sleep or spin. It is harmful, and I'll lost data, I must find a way to reduce latency. Q2:P(M,N) means pick N elements from a set with M elemnts, where every picked element is unique.Q3:The M is defined by us, we can choose one.We spilit the global to sub-hashtable like a two-level hashtables :)

Answer (score 0):

I think complexity of your algorithm does not worth it's benefits. Practically there are many more simpler solutions. Before you start it's better to determine usage pattern. I can summarize them this way:

- HashTable readonly - initialize it once, reads are safe.
- Append only or read/write ratio is high - recreate hashtable each write and use Interlocked.CompareExchange to replace.
- Read/write ratio is low - use spinwait based Reader/Writer lock.

And remember - the only way to determine the best solution for the problem is careful testing and measurement!